# CVC complex type errors

Tags: xml, eclipse

I have imported a project from SVN. I am using eclipse, maven. Now I am getting around 200 errors related to cvc.complexType as bellow. Plz note that I already had other errors regarding to missed jars. I am not sure if that is a case here.

[image]

More details about the errors:

Code :

Related error:

```
    cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with 
 element 'many-to-one'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
 persistence/orm":many-to-many, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
 persistence/orm":element-collection, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
 persistence/orm":embedded, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
 persistence/orm":transient}' is expected.
```

---

Code:

### Error: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'nullable' is not allowed to appear in element 'basic'.

Code : DATETIME
Related Error: 
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'DATETIME' is not facet-
     valid with respect to enumeration '[DATE, TIME, TIMESTAMP]'. It 
     must be a value from the enumeration.
    - cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'DATETIME' of element 
     'temporal' is not valid.

Update : I found out that it is related to JPA or Hibernate. Not sure though. So the schemas are

```
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm 
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
```

Comment: It could be any number of things, but with the information you've provided we have no way of even starting to guess.  Clearly a path is incorrectly set or missing, but we can't help based on what you've shown.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks for the reply. I have multiple xml files. I have received this project from a teammate. He said if you run this with maven there shouldn't be any problems. The only diff is that I am using eclipse and he had Netbeans. So I edit my question and add more details. Tnx.